# Use JCarousel with pager

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, pager, drupal-jcarousel

I would like to use the Drupal module JCarousel with a pager. But apperently, there is some kind of bug or error which doesn't allow me to use a pager... All I get is this error, twice...

```
 - The jCarousel style cannot be used with a pager. Disable the "Use
   pager" option for this display. 
 - The jCarousel style cannot be used
   with a pager. Disable the "Use pager" option for this display.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) plugin ?

It allow to make Carousels in a really powerfull way then just needs to by styled. The last version allow to make it far more customizable.

Comment: Ok, great module!! Do you happen to know if I can use both the pager and the automatic sliding effect? If so, how? :)

Comment: Yes it is possible with the last version of the module. You just have ton configure it properly, it is not so hard.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is you can't I'm afraid, the error message is telling the truth!

There's a detailed discussion about why you can't and what you need to do instead on [this post](http://drupal.org/node/1136570), I think [this comment](http://drupal.org/node/1136570#comment-4938972) in particular will tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: You need to implement `jcarousel_form_views_ui_add_form_alter` by the looks of it, you can either do it in a custom module if you want to keep the code of the jCarousel module clean...if you're not bothered though just put it straight into the `jcarousel.module` file. Either way it will need to be in a `.module` file, once you've added the function make sure you clear Drupal's caches so the new hook gets picked up

Comment: Alright, makes sense. I'm fairly new to drupal, and I get an error the function `jcarousel_form_views_ui_add_form_alter()` cannot be declared... Do I need to replace it with another kind of function?

Comment: I guess that error would be 'cannot be re-declared'? If so just do a search for that function name within the jCarousel folder...when you find it just make the changes to the already existing function.